# Java 8 lambda с нестатическими методами класса

Tags: java, lambda

Здравствуйте.

Вот начал ковырять лямбды в новой джаве. Есть одна интересная вещь. Функциональному интерфейсу можно присвоить метод, если по сигнатуре совпадает с методом интерфейса. Допустим,

`Comparator<Integer> myComp = Integer::compare;`

Этот метод статический, на вход принимает два параметра, все хорошо. Но можно сделать это же с нестатическим методом. Допустим

`Comparator<Integer> myComp = Integer::compareTo`.

Данный метод нестатический, к тому же он принимает только 1 параметр. Насколько я понял, все методы в джаве являются статическими, просто если метод нестатический, то ему передается дополнительный параметр this, указывающий на инстанс объекта. То есть фактически передается так:

`compareTo(this,Integer value)`.

Логично было предположить, что результат будет неизвестно какой. Так как мы собираемся сравнивать объект с интом. 
НО все же все работает отлично.

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = Integer::compareTo;
Comparator<Integer> comparator2 = Integer::compare;
System.out.println(comparator.compare(1,2));
System.out.println(comparator2.compare(1,2));
```

Вот это работает одинаково.

Продебажил по ходу вызовов методов.

При вызове метода compare у comparator, то бишь без создания инстанса, в this.value уже находится число, переданное первым параметром и соответственно объекта класса созданный. 
Собственно, сам вопрос: как это все работает? При вызове компилятор смотрит, чтобы у класса было единственное поле, которое совпадает с аргрументом метода, и если так и есть, то создает неявно объект класса, инициализируя поле первым аргументом? Или как это работает?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У данного применения лямбд есть 3 варианта:

object::instanceMethod - передаем метод указанного объекта, при соответствии по параметрам;

Сlass::staticMethod - передаем статик метод указанного класса при соответствии по параметрам;

Class::instanceMethod - передается указанный метод класса.

Не рассмативаем вариант с передачей ссылки на метод-конструктор. Наш случай третий как раз в этом списке, и у него есть простая хитрость: первый параметр становится целевым объектом метода, то есть ссылкой this.

Если развернуть ваше

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = Integer::compareTo;
```

то мы получим

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = (x,y) -> x.compareTo(y);
```

И всё становится на свои места.

Вот [здесь (английская документация)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) и [здесь (на русском)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/224593/) - более подробная информация.